Why I cannot define my post Api with a json body and a token header with Axum?
I use Axum 0.7 and I want to define a POST Api with the handler below
    async fn add_key(
        Json(customer): Json<AddKeyRequest>,
        security_token: SecurityToken,
    ) -> impl IntoResponse {  
       ...
    }

The FromRequest trait has been defined for SecurityToken
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct SecurityToken(pub String);

#[async_trait]
impl<S> FromRequest<S> for SecurityToken
where
    S: Send + Sync,
{
    type Rejection = (StatusCode, String);
    async fn from_request(req: Request, _state: &S) -> Result<Self, Self::Rejection> {
        let headers = req.headers();
        headers
            .get("token")
            .and_then(|value| value.to_str().ok())
            .map(|value| SecurityToken(value.to_string()))
            .ok_or((
                StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Missing or invalid token header".into(),
            ))
    }
}

I get the compilation error :
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(Json<AddKeyRequest>, SecurityToken) -> impl Future<Output = impl IntoResponse> {add_key}: Handler<_, _>` is not satisfied
   --> key-manager\src/main.rs:162:40
    |
162 |         .route("/key", post(add_key));
    |                                   ---- ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Handler<_, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(AddKeyRequest>, SecurityToken) -> impl Future<Output = impl IntoResponse> {add_key}`
    |                                   |
    |                                   required by a bound introduced by this call

It's only when I do a POST, in the case of my token in a GET handler, along with a Path parameter, I don't have any problem to compile (and the Api works fine).
async fn read_key(
    Path(customer_code): Path<String>,
    security_token: SecurityToken,
) -> WebType<CustomerKeyReply> {
    ...
}


I think I found the problem.
I must implement
async fn from_request_parts(parts: &mut Parts, _state: &S) -> Result<Self, Self::Rejection> 

from the FromRequestParts trait
